# How to mock an object created via Class.newInstance(className)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to add unit tests to some legacy code that has a String class name passed to it and that creates an object implementing a particular handler interface using `Class.newInstance(String className)`.  I can control the class name I'm passing, I can get a pointer to the new handler object (via a `getHandler()` call), and I would like to observe calls to it using Mockito.

My current solution is:

1. Create a new test class `TestHandler` that implements the interface.
2. Have that test class contain a Mockito mock object that also implements the interface.
3. **Manually** pass through all the interface methods to the mock object.
4. Make the mock object accessible via a `getMock()` method.
5. Observe the object by making verify() calls to `objectUnderTest.getHandler().getMock()`.

This works, but feels a little inelegant, especially having to manually write all the pass-thru methods.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: what exactly do you want to test? that an instance of the correct runtime type is created when you call a certain method?

Comment: I want to verify that methods are being called on the newly created object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, you're running into the same problems as trying to test a newly-created instance using `new`; the `Class.newInstance` (probably properly `Class.forName(foo).newInstance()`) doesn't hurt you, but doesn't help you either.

As a side note, your `TestHandler` sounds like a general purpose delegate implementation, which sounds pretty useful anyway (particularly if you ever need to write a Handler wrapper). If it is, you might want to promote it to be adjacent to your Handler in your production code tree.

Though I recognize that you mention legacy code, this becomes very easy if you are allowed to refactor to include a testing seam. (Ignoring reflective exceptions here for ease of explanation.)

```
public ReturnType yourMethodUnderTest(String className) {
  return yourMethodUnderTest(Class.newInstance(className));
}

/** Package private for testing. */
public ReturnType yourMethodUnderTest(Handler handler) {
  return yourMethodUnderTest(Class.newInstance(className));
}
```

You could also extract the object creation and replace it in your test:

```
/** Instance field, package-private to replace in tests. */
Function<String, Handler> instanceCreator =
    ( x -> (Handler) Class.forName(x).newInstance());

public ReturnType yourMethodUnderTest(String className) {
  Handler handler = instanceCreator.apply(className);
  // ...
}
```

You could even just extract it to a method and replace it in your test:

```
public ReturnType yourMethodUnderTest(String className) {
  Handler handler = createHandler(className);
  // ...
}

/** Package private for testing. */
Handler createHandler(String className) {
  return Class.forName(className).newInstance();
}

@Test public void yourTest() {
  // Manually replace createHandler. You could also use a Mockito spy here.
  ObjectUnderTest objectUnderTest = new ObjectUnderTest() {
    @Override Handler createHandler(String className) {
      return mock(Handler.class);
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

---

Side note: Even though Mockito creates a named dynamic type, you almost certainly will not be able to hack it in and allow your code to create it by name. This is because the call to `mock` [registers the instance within Mockito's internal state](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/bef687727f9dbd525a3fef84c5f5e81b7fc98bab/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/MockitoCore.java#L56).

```
// BAD: Unlikely to work
@Test public void yourTest() {
  objectUnderTest.methodUnderTest(
      mock(Handler.class).getClass().getName());
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a great way to move forward and refactor once I get unit tests in place, which would then allow me to remove the mock-object wrapper that I'm concerned about.

Answer (score 0):

Create a public method where you will place the logic to fetch the newInstance of the class

```
ClassA objectClassA=createNewInstance(className);
```

likewise,and

```
public ClassA createInstance(String className){
 return (ClassA) (Class.forName(className)).newInstance();
}
```

Now suppose we were creating an instance of classA inside of ClassB
then in TestClass of B, we can simply mock this createInstance method

```
doReturn(mockClassA).when(mockClassB).createInstance(className);
```